# WPF - Windows 7 - 64bit - No content rendered

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

Dev machine: Windows 7 64bit desktop. Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

Not sure what the cause is but the behavior is this:
I can develop in VS on this desktop just fine. Have done some class libraries and windows forms with no issues from what I have seen. However in WPF project I cannot get any content to render in window when I run the project. A simple hello world in wpf like this:

```
<Window x:Class="test"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Hello" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
</Grid>
```

Renders an empty window with a white background. 
Also, I have noticed that if I resize the window the white area does not resize correctly with the window. Is this a graphics driver issue or a framework install issue or?

Comment: Seeing as Win 7 is now in RTM, this may be the portent of many new   headaches for developers. (Just when you thought you've coded around all the black box issues, MS releases a set of new ones!)

Comment: I just tried this sample on my own box (identical setup) and no issues.  Something else is awry here.  Video card drivers (this is a stretch)?

Comment: Just tried it on a VM too, just in case this might be your setup as well.  Works fine there too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on working scenarios. I am investigating driver issues now. I have a ASUS 9600 GT Silent card. I installed the RTM back in June and did have some issues getting compliant drivers. Will update with any new results ...

Comment: Added answer to this question, it was video driver. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by Anderson Imes in his comments, it ended up being the Video card drivers which I had installed before NVidia released a new, supposedly Windows 7 compliant, driver on July 7th. Updated the drivers and Hello World is back in business.

Comment: It did not solve my problem . I am using Fluent:RibbonWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue, but all was fine until just a few days ago.  WPF projects just just stopped working for me, same as you describe.  I suspected a recent windows update, so i uninstalled them, rebooted and still does not work.  There is no available 64 bit driver available for my video card (Mobility Radeon™ X1400)

Any other suggestions out there?

Answer (score -2):

It's now 2013 and WPF Still renders a blank screen.  Looks like WPF is not ready for prime time yet.  Going back to browser applications.

Comment: the original answer still stands. check your hardware and drivers. WPF is quite ready and will be around for a bit I think ;-)