# wpf window entirely black

Tags: wpf, window

I sell a WPF application, on one customer machine (out of several hundreds) the entire application window is black, anyone know what's going on?

The machine is running Windows XP with .net 3.5SP1, the graphic adapter is GeForce 6200 with two monitors (disabling one monitor doesn't solve the problem).

Setting "Compatibility settings" to "256 colors" solves the problem (but it's not a viable solution, I need more colors for the app to look good).

The application is yaTimer ( http://www.nbdtech.com/yaTimer/ ), it has custom window chrome based on the techniques described in this post http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx in the "Office 2007 without Aero" section.

If anyone can give me a clue as to what's going on I'll be very thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem too, by using the same technique.

Comment: @Luis Filipe - No, I didn't solve this, the customer who had this problem decided to switch to a different product (not surprising) and I didn't get complaints about this problem from anyone else, hope you find the solution

Comment: I just got an 'all black' wpf window render also, while developing. My problem was I was calling a method on a null object: obj.Method() (obj is null). Uuusually that throws a runtime error, but for some reason this time the bug manifested with this all black thing. Haven't figured out why.

Answer (score 9):

We ([www.novamind.com](http://www.novamind.com)) had multiple customers in the past having similar issues where the application wouldn't draw correctly or not at all. Reasons were:

- graphic driver is not up-to-date.
- Windows theme is corrupt. Changing the Windows theme to something different and back again, solved the issue.
- Windows is running in a virtual machine. Most virtual machines have a experimental hardware acceleration feature which often does not properly support WPF applications. - Turning off the hardware acceleration solves the problem.

This can also help:

- Re-install the .NET framework - sometimes the installation is corrupt.
- Make sure that all the recent Windows Updates are installed.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I could not identify the source of the problem as it did not occur again. I awarded the bounty for this one because it seemed the most plausible problem. Sorry for all the others left behind.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue only with the GlassFrame enabled in the window chome.

Try setting GlassFraneThickness to 0 and your window will render again. You will lose the Glass frame though, but better than a black app.

```
<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <shell:WindowChrome CaptionHeight="32" GlassFrameThickness="0" ResizeBorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="0" />
</shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Maybe you can also try to force the window to repaint. Im my case the window content showed when i moved the window to the other monitor or out of the viewport and in again, so a repaint seems to do the job.

In the Microsoft.Windows.Shell Sourcecode there is a function *_FixupWindows7Issues()* (in the *WindowChromeWorker* class) which should fix the problem according to it's comment, but obviously doesn't...

Comment: Setting GlassFrameThickness="0" fixed to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with override the window template.
I figured out that if you but the inherit window style in Themes/Generic.xaml it works. But in any other Resource you will get a black window. (VS 2008 - WPF 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround is to force software mode rendering:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.rendermode.aspx

In 3.5 this can be set on a per window basis http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndtarget.rendermode%28VS.90%29.aspx and in 4.0 there is additionally a process wide setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode.aspx

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as i have time available

Comment: This doesn't address actual problem; I can't consider this as an "answer" but a speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a WPF application when debugging. 
In the Debug - Options, navigate to Debugging - General and de-select the option to "show runtime tools in application" under "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML" The next time you run the app it won't overlap the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to the problem I had the other night and posted here:

[Question: WPF - No Content Rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258316/wpf-windows-7-64bit-no-content-rendered)

Check the video card drivers as one possibility

Comment: I have this issue on a remote desktop connection. From my computer works fine; From another computer it displays a black window

Comment: I've had this issue with ATI drivers on mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing latest DirectX package on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue with a black window in WPF, in a VB 2010/.Net 4.0 solution where every other window worked just fine. The culprit turned out to be the manner in which I was toggling the visibility on, using the following 3 commands below. The solution was to remove all but the first line, the one with the Visibility property reference (removing only the .Show line would cause it to render correctly the first time but black thereafter):

```
             Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
             Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.Show()
             Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.Activate()
```

I'd never before had an issue with this series of commands to Show a WPF window, so I guess I got into a rut and never bothered to check whether it was the optimal way to go about it; out of habit, I just pasted the code as needed to summon up windows. It still works for every other window in every other solution I've ever written, but it caused this one particular window to turn black. At first it only occurred intermittently in one particular routine, then became permanent for unknown reasons. None of the following lines of code I experimented with made any difference:

```
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.InvalidateVisual()
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.InvalidateArrange()
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.UpdateLayout()
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.BringIntoView()
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
            Application.MisbehavingBlackWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal
```

Stripping all of the controls out of the window had no effect; it would still turn black if it was populated only by a single TextBlock. On the other hand, a pattern did emerge after I tried executing it from other routines, particularly if pasted the first code block inside one that called up another window. If I inserted it just prior to a code block like the one below, the window turned black; if I inserted it after, it did not.

```
                Application.OtherWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                Application.OtherWindow.Show()
                Application.OtherWindow.Activate()
```

The solution works (so far) even if the window is hidden using a Window.Hide() command. I already had one included in an event Sub inside the offending window, which was triggered whenever the window lost focus. Toggling it back on using the Visibility property still does the trick without requiring any changes to that .Hide statement.

I hopes this helps anyone who runs across this irritating problem. So far, most of the solutions I've seen scattered across the Internet seem to be based on things like Windows Themes, graphics cards and other external variables, but we can apparently fix at least some instances of this right in our .Net code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using virtual machine disable 3D acceleration :)

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you delete the initial grid from your window.
You always need something as a base to display controls on top of, and deleting everything within your window and adding controls to the, now empty, window will result in the entire thing becoming black when you actually run the application.

Comment: 1. You don't need "a base to display controls on top of", the Window class itself is capable of hosting a control inside it (that's how it can hold the grid), you can easily test it by creating a window with just a button inside it.  2. If you create a totally empty window it will have the windows background color that is usually white not black

Answer (score 0):

For users landing here when searching for .net 6.0 or .net 8.0 upgrade and then having a black application:
We removed all our AssemblyInfo.cs during upgrade, since we now use a solution wide Directory.Build.props.
One of the AssemblyInfo.cs contained an Theme-block, which is required by the WPF-engine, so it loads Generic.xaml for all windows.

Solution is to create a new <choose_your_name>.cs file (best in the project containing your themes\Generic.xaml) with that content:

```
using System.Windows;

// We need this, so Theming (and loading of generic.xaml) works
// This was previously inside the AssemblyInfo.cs.
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
)]
```

Please also check your previous AssemblyInfo.cs-ThemeInfo-block, chances are, that you have a different value for ResourceDictionaryLocation.